Squelize Data type for a Foreign key
In my Sequelize user model declaration I have:
User.associate = function (models) 
        {
            User.hasMany(models.r_inGroup);
            User.hasMany(models.r_inSession, 
                  {foreignKey: 'userName', 
                   type: DataTypes.STRING
                  });  
                // this willl create a column in r_inSession named userName and foreign key to User
                // based on:   https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/
        };

After its execution a column named 'userName' in the table r_inSession (same name with its model class) is created but with data type int. Yet, I need it to be STRING. How could this be solved?

Just define it explicitly in Session model and don't forget to mark it either as PK or unique field
